# Help on help results in HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: bug, status-completed

A request to http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help?help results in an `HTTP 500` with `Content-Type: application/json` and an HTML body.

Comment: It would return a result, but then space-time would fold in on itself and kill us all...

Comment: Well, how am I supposed to learn how to use the API help, if there's no help on the help? I feel lost... :-)

Comment: @Franci: I feel for you, man.

Comment: @Kevin - love the bug fix! :-)

Comment: **Haven't we seen enough of Sean Connery?!?**

Answer (score 1):

Use http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help ?

Comment: This would give me the help for everything other method. But it has no help on the help method itself. :-)